# Microsoft Advertising error

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, ads

I never had problems with Microsoft Advertising until yesterday...
Yesterday I had lot of crash in my app due to Microsoft Advertising.
The symbol name of the event is:
Microsoft_Advertising!Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject::[Windows::UI::Xaml::IDependencyObject]::SetValue

Someone else have this problem ?
How can I solve this problem?
(my app is a Windows 10 universal app (c# + XAML))

Stack trace:

1 Windows_UI_Xaml DirectUI::DependencyPropertyHandle::GetDP 0x2E380F

2 Windows_UI_Xaml DirectUI::DependencyObject::SetValue 0x27

3 Microsoft_Advertising Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject::[Windows::UI::Xaml::IDependencyObject]::SetValue 0x48

4 Microsoft_Advertising Microsoft::Advertising::WinRT::UI::AdControl::ApplicationId::[Microsoft::Advertising::WinRT::UI::__IAdControlPublicNonVirtuals::ApplicationId]::set 0x6E

5 Microsoft_Advertising Microsoft::Advertising::WinRT::UI::AdControl::[Microsoft::Advertising::WinRT::UI::__IAdControlPublicNonVirtuals]::__abi_Microsoft_Advertising_WinRT_UI___IAdControlPublicNonVirtuals____abi_set_ApplicationId 0x2A

6 App2_7ff97fad0000 $102_McgInterop::ComCallHelpers.ComCall__HRESULT 0x87

7 App2_7ff97fad0000 $102_McgInterop::ForwardComSharedStubs.Proc_string__ 0x6D

8 App2_7ff97fad0000 $97_Microsoft::AdMediator::Universal::MicrosoftAdvertising::MicrosoftAdvertisingAdAdapter.InstantiateControl 0x249

9 App2_7ff97fad0000 $56_Microsoft::AdMediator::Core::BaseAdAdapter::__c__DisplayClass72_0._LoadControl_b__0 0x20

10 App2_7ff97fad0000 $56_Microsoft::AdMediator::Core::BaseAdAdapter::__c__DisplayClass76_0._RunOnDispatcher_b__0 0x22

11 App2_7ff97fad0000 $16_System::Threading::WaitCallback.Invoke 0xF

12 App2_7ff97fad0000
$84_Internal::WinRT::Interop::WinRTCallbacks::__c__DisplayClass14_0._SubmitLongRunningThreadpoolWork_b__0 0x10

13 App2_7ff97fad0000 $102_Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler__Impl::Vtbl.Invoke__STUB 0x2A

14 Windows_UI Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessInvokeItem 0x23C

15 Windows_UI Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessMessage 0x1A4

16 Windows_UI Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages 0x1A2

17 Windows_UI Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents 0xA8

18 Windows_UI_Xaml CJupiterWindow::RunCoreWindowMessageLoop 0x65

19 Windows_UI_Xaml DirectUI::DXamlCore::RunMessageLoop 0x47

20 twinapi_appcore Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run 0x46

21 twinapi_appcore _lambda_d86ebb20270fa8a99766b2537cc9a251_::_helper_func_cdecl_ 0x100

22 SHCore _WrapperThreadProc 0xF0

23 kernel32 BaseThreadInitThunk 0x22

24 ntdll RtlUserThreadStart 0x34

and the failure string name is:

STOWED_EXCEPTION_8000ffff_Microsoft.Advertising.dll!Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject::[Windows::UI::Xaml::IDependencyObject]::SetValue

when I test my app on VisualSudio 2015 I have this error:
Exception thrown at 0x74CD3E28 (KernelBase.dll) in App2.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x800F1000, 0x00000053, 0x07A0CE9C).
windows\dxaml\xcp\components\vsm\visualstatemanagerdatasource.cpp(260)\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!055146AF: (caller: 0522D02D) Exception(1) tid(5168) 800F1000 Aucun composant installé n’a été détecté.
Exception thrown at 0x74CD3E28 in App2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: wil::ResultException at memory location 0x07A0C448.
Exception thrown at 0x74CD3E28 in App2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
windows\dxaml\xcp\components\vsm\cvisualstatemanager2.cpp(131)\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!05514C93: (caller: 05439146) ReturnHr(1) tid(5168) 800F1000 Aucun composant installé n’a été détecté.

But my app is the same as before...I don't understand (I just updated admediator...)

Comment: "Someone else have this problem?" It's hard to tell what the problem is, given that you've only said it's "lot crash [..] due to Microsoft Advertising". I'm sure you have more detail - if you have an exception, then a full stack trace including the exception type and message would help...

Comment: sorry... I had the Stack trace

Comment: And an exception type and message?

Comment: I added the failure string name

Comment: Right, well at least that's a bit more information - although it would be nice if you could format it a bit more readably. At least now someone else who *has* seen the same error is more likely to be able to recognize it.

Comment: I also have been seeing this in my UWP app, although I haven't been able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes other developers are seeing this issue, too.

Please upvote the problem [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28207687-df4e-4918-8aff-6cb2b71ac13a/ad-mediator-crashes-app-on-startup).